# CSS targeting specific images

Tags: css, image, dimensions, targeting

I am looking for a way to target a specific image with CSS, if this is even possible.

I am running a CMS where the users can upload images and put them on their pages. I would like a way to target images with specific dimensions.

So the question is, **can you make a css line target a image or object with certain dimensional specifications** ?

I would imagine something like :

```
img#width:400px { float :left; }
```

(to make images that are 400 pixels wide have float:left)

I know i could give the image a class or an id, but it would be lost when the customer plays around in the cms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
img[width="400"]{
   float:left;
}
```

This will make any image that have the attribute set to 400 float left:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="400" />
```

Note: this will only work if the width attribute is set. Will not work if the image is 400px wide but does not have a width attribute set.

Comment: the idea is to match both the attribute and value in html <img attribute="value"> and in css img[attribute="value"]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) this should work

```
img[width=400]
```

but I haven't tried it