# CSS targeting with 'AND' and 'OR' function in style.css

Tags: css, image

In this article: [CSS targeting specific images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799939/css-targeting-specific-images), Nils Munch explained how to 'hooks' specifid images by CSS, here an example:

```
img[width="400"]{
float:left;
}
```

It's working perfectly for me, i also hooked classes:

```
img.forum-icon {
background: #ffffff;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

But now i found an image 'un-hookable' because has not specified size, has not a class... I should not hook all images on the theme like with this:

```
.img {
background: #ffffff;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

There is a way to hook as for example with the programming 'and' functions?
as for example:

```
If is 400px and not class x then
```

Or better all images less specified class or sizes:

```
.img (but not x class or not x width){
background: #ffffff;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

EDIT:
Thank you all,
i found useful this:

```
img:not([src="http://www.love4wellness.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logo.png"]) {
    background: #ffffff;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

To close this request i need if there is a way to add multiple images to my filter, as for example:

```
img:not([src=image1], [src=image2], [src=image3]) {
    background: #ffffff;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

I tried several ways but not working...

Other, unfotunately i had to add too many picture to the filter (if it's possible to add more than one) also add to thumbnails too... really a har work for a shop online website..

My new question shold be more simple:

I want to customize only images posted in BuddyPress pages... this is the page of example: http://www.love4wellness.it/groups/benvenuto/

As you see the img of the first thread have not border, and have no hooks like class and/or custom css file to edit...
There is a way to make it hookable?

Thanks a lot for you patience...

Comment: You should try to use a descendant selector.

Comment: Does the image have a width attribute?

Comment: No, unfortunately it have not attributes, else i know i should hook by this..

Comment: @StefanoCamaiani I have revised my answer based on your edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**:

Keep things simple. Suppose you want to add a red border to anonymous images, you can write:

```css
/* add red border to all images */
img { border: 1px solid red; }
/* remove border if image has class or width attribute */
img[class], img[width] { border: none; }
```

**Solution 2:**

Use CSS3 [`:not`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) pseudo-class:

```css
/* if is 400px and not class x then */
img[width="400"]:not(.someclass) { }
/* not x class or not x width */
img:not(.someclass), img:not([width="400"]) { }
```

---

Note:

- The `:not` selector accepts a [*simple selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) so `:not(.foo, .bar)` will not work but `:not(.foo):not(.bar)` will.
- If the images to exclude have something common inside the `src` attribute you can target (or exclude them) like `[src*="/some/path/"]`.

Answer (score 0):

If organise your declarations in order, then they will be overwritten/applied only if the condition is met

```
// standard img with no class of width hook
.img {
background: #ffffff;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
}

// applied to the above styles, to images with this hook.
img[width="400"]{
float:left;
}

// applied to all the above styles, to images with this hook.
img.forum-icon {
background: #ffffff;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED:

I directly hooked the container:

```
.activity-content img{
background: #ffffff;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Thanks to all